# Error when Calling Jquery Function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am getting the error at the line :

validate();

When I trying to call the following jQuery function

```
 (function ($) { 
        "use strict";    
         var methods = {
     validate: function () {
                 if ($(this).is("form"))
                     return methods._validateFields(this);
                 else {
                     // field validation
                     var form = $(this).closest('form');
                     var options = form.data('jqv');
                     var r = methods._validateField($(this), options);

                     if (options.onSuccess && options.InvalidFields.length == 0)
                         options.onSuccess();
                     else if (options.onFailure && options.InvalidFields.length > 0)
                         options.onFailure();
                     return r;
                 }
             }
    }
```

Using the following JavaScript, I am getting the error at validation function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {
        $(function () {
            validate();
        });
    }
</script>
```

The function validate has been described in the above jQuery.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: So you're defining `validate` method inside `methods` object and later on you're trying to fire the `validate` as if it would be some regular function defined in local scope. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: so something like this  method.validate() ??

Comment: a method inside a method???!!!!

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'methods' is undefined

Comment: I am trying to call the javascript fuction from the textchanged event of the date control to validate the entire page

Comment: You should give us a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we could have a more accurated view of your code problem

Comment: I dont know how to use it :-)

Comment: I think you have missed last lines in the first code snippet - how do you close `(function ($) { ` ? It needs something like `})(jQuery)` in the last line and it's not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it !!

I have called  jQuery("#aspnetForm").valid();

I Have created a function called valid()

Like this :

```
 $.fn.valid = function (method) {
           methods._validateFields(this);
     };
```

Now its fine .... !

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose `methods` to other functions - put it in the global scope.

So either use the global `window` object and do:

```
window.methods =
```

For example:

```
(function ($) { 
        "use strict";    
         window.methods = {
             validate: function () {...
```

Or define it first outside of `(function($){...})`

For example:

```
var methods = {};
(function ($) { 
        "use strict";    
         methods = {
             validate: function () {...
```

Notice no `var` before second `methods`.

Then you can call `methods.validate()`

**Also:** ensure you close `(function ($) {` with `})(jQuery)` - it's missing from the code that you posted.

Comment: It will be enough to do `window.methods =` instead of `var methods =` - then `methods` will be accessible in the global scope (through `window`) and all members of `methods` will also be accessible.

Comment: Its not working !!! i am gettint the error as "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".. but this error i am getting at the place where i am calling the  jQuery("#aspnetForm").validationEngine();   ..but i think instead of calling the validate() i can call the line jQuery("#aspnetForm").validationEngine();..let me see

Comment: window.methods giving a syntax error as well ..its says "expecting ;"

Comment: Well, you might be missing `;` somewhere. On what line is it "expecting ;" ?

Comment: Also, I can't see `jQuery("#aspnetForm").validationEngine();` anywhere in the code that you posted so it might be a completely different problem.

Comment: i got it i put like this window methods...actualy its should be like this window.methods..i will try now

Comment: No its not working Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: On which line? The `methods.validate()` line?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
 var methods = {
     validate: function () {
                 if ($(this).is("form"))
                     return methods._validateFields(this);
                 else {
                     // field validation
                     var form = $(this).closest('form');
                     var options = form.data('jqv');
                     var r = methods._validateField($(this), options);

                     if (options.onSuccess && options.InvalidFields.length == 0)
                         options.onSuccess();
                     else if (options.onFailure && options.InvalidFields.length > 0)
                         options.onFailure();
                     return r;
                 }
             }

<script type="text/javascript">
    function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {
            methods.validate();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: methods.validate(); i have tried inside javascript ..no hope its not working ..did you changed anything othere than in Javascript code? did you made any changes in Jquery?